# Creating a file of Certain size in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I want to create a file of certain size (26MB) in the cypress test.

I don't want to include a real file in the fixtures as it would clutter my repository.

I can't use an environment file as this would be run locally and on CI. It needs to be platform independent.

Is there a way I can do this in the test without the usage of system scripts?

Is there anything we can do with cy.task method?

Comment: You want a file - but not a real file - what did you have in mind? What are you intending to do with it?

Comment: @Fay the intension here is to test e.g. forms that offer a file upload. I have the same problem - I want to test that the maximum file size is not exceeded so I need to ideally generate a file that exceeds that size. As the max file size could potentially change, it would be nice to dynamically set the file size.

Comment: Ah @hendik, thank you for your explanation. The answer by Joonas is perfect for the case you describe.

Answer (score 4):

There's not a great argument for not having a permanent file.

But you can write the file in a `before()` hook.

```js
before(() => {
  cy.writeFile('cypress/downloads/file26mb.dat',  Buffer.alloc(26*1024*1024, '0'))
})
```

You can delete it in an `after()` hook via a task

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        deleteFile(path) {
          fs.unlinkSync(path)
          return null
        },
      })
    },
  },
})
```

```js
after(() => {
  cy.task('deleteFile, 'cypress/downloads/file26mb.dat')
})
```

Using the downloads folder means if the file is not cleaned up for some reason (a crash), Cypress cleans it up anyway.